# SQL Server on Kubernetes (aks) login for SA failed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, sql-server-2019

I am trying to deploy a custom SQL Server 2019 docker image from my docker hub repository to a kubernetes cluster (aks) but not able to log in to the DB instance from outside. It says login for user 'sa' failed.

I have verified the password requirements and literally tried using the same used in Microsoft docs but still can't log in to SQL Server.

Tried using **sqlcmd** and **Azure Data Studio** and I know it is reaching the server because the errorlog has the following error:

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8
> Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided.

Comment: Check the SQL Server's logs. Can you see the attempt? If so, what is the error? If not, then the connection isn't reaching the instance.

Comment: I came across an interesting issue where on Linux characters in passwords were getting misinterpreted / mangled. Things like `$` just wouldn't work, so I changed my password pattern to use `#` instead of `$`. If you have any non-alphanumeric characters you may want to try changing them (of course you'll have to log in using a different account in order to change it, or tear it down and bring it back up again).

Comment: *"login failed for user 'sa'"* isn't the full error in the logs. The logs will tell you the full error, such as the password being incorrect.

Comment: What @Larnu is saying is that _the SQL Server errorlog_ (not any log from your application) will include additional information, including [a useful state number](https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456) and, usually, additional context.

Comment: Yes, so, you are not entering the right password (and, again, it might be because of special characters, like `$`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand 's thoughts on the password here, could very well be spot on. Might be worth changing it to a different secure password (without a $ in it) and try that. Otherwise you really are passing the wrong password.

Comment: Was just going through your blog @AaronBertrand. Pretty neat ! But not sure what I am doing wrong guys.. tried typing it out in the sqlcmd command line arg letter for letter, pasting it directly into the ADS field. changed it around a couple times etc. But if you guys are absolutely sure its a password issue, I'll have to keep trying I guess. Larnu, i just did remove the $ and replaced it with a # but didn't make any difference.

Comment: You need to _create a password_ without `$`. You can't just change what you're entering to authenticate.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear on that part. Here's what I have been doing form the very begining  -
1. Password doesn't work
2. Delete all resources (secret - where I store the password, pod, service etc) from the cluster
3. "Recreate" all resources with "new secret" (new password) to try it out
4. Wait till the container spins up and the DB instance is ready
5. Try logging in with the "newly created password"
6. Go to step 1

Comment: Some of the passwords, I have tried so far (if it helps):
1. MyC0m9l&xP@ssw0rd (straight from MS docs)
2. Password123#
3. Password117@
4. P@ssw0rd
5. Pa$$w0rd1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested the same passwords, in my local docker environment and incidently, all of them gave the same error whenever I spun the container. After a few options, I used a simple password which worked locally and in k8s as well.

Have raised an SR with MS to understand password policy reqs. as to why some passwords didn't work. Event the one provided in their docs.

Thanks @Larnu and @Aaron Bertrand for your time and inputs.